# Decrypting help on IDA Pro/XXTEA

Tags: key, cocos2d-android, xxtea

I'm working with a game that is no longer available, i want to remake it but when i try to decrypting the game i found out it made by cocos2d game engine and the lua script is encrypted in xxtea. And now i'm trying to find the key of it in the libgame.so but i couldn't find the exact key so i wanna ask for some help to find the key. I don't know much about reverse engineering so it's pretty hard for me to do it

i think [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G57jb.png) is where i can get the key but i still can't figure out which one is the key and what is the value of it.
[this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KiyxDMrgEdW_j6oviNpXIJuZl08O2eaC/view?usp=sharing) is the libgame.so file.
[this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k9RmP0n2sdNLZtPJay8c7uF10q-KQyKD/view?usp=sharing) is a lua file if you want to check your key.
Pls help me with it. Thanks